# How to change the style of jquery contextmenu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jquery context menu with the Jqgrid .I am able to get the context menu options on right click but i am not able to change the default styling of the context menu.For example , if my context menu options are greater to some words they are coming down in next line which i dont want..

Here is the HTML..

```
<div class="contextMenu" id="myMenu1" style="display:none; width:auto;">
    <ul style="width: 200px">
     <li id="Reservation">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="float:left"></span>
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana">Reservation Options</span>
        </li>
        <li id="CheckIn">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="float:left"></span>
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana">CheckIn</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now in the above context menu , The very first option `Reservation Options` i am getting in two lines which i dont want..
Please help me to update the css.I tried to increase the width of the ul list but its not working ..
Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Create a new CSS file and add all style to it and include that;

to over-ride inline style you have to use `!important;`

```
.contextMenu
{
   /*Your context menu styling here*/
}

.contextMenu ul
{
   width: 500px !important; /*or Your desired width here */
}

.contextMenu ul li
{
   white-space: nowarp;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: But the styling has been done here only like ` <ul style="width: 200px">`   ..I tried increasing the `ul` width here from `200px` to `500px` but its not working..

Comment: add !important in style as well so that inline style may be over-ridden.

Comment: One query ,Can i change the CSS inline only because i dont want to add the new css ..Every thing is fine except the width .So can anyhow i can change or upgrade it in this my original code i.e. `<div class="contextMenu" id="myMenu1" style="display:none; width:auto;">
    <ul style="width: 200px">
     <li id="Reservation">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="float:left"></span>

Comment: Just search where the width 200px where is being set, and change it, if its not in HTML then it would be set up through JS.

Comment: alternatively you can add <style>.contextMenu ul
{
   width: 500px !important; /*or Your desired width here */
}</style> tag for in file styling.

Comment: I tried this one also but its not working ..Still they are coming in two lines ..Width is not getting increased

Comment: It would be great you add a fiddle. So I can help you better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63991/discussion-between-hansal-mehta-and-aamir-shahzad).

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?  I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: @ijason03 Please share the link or create a demo I will help you fix the issue.

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  The width was being set in the js file and no other styling would override it.  I just modified the js file.

Answer (score 1):

contextmenu has a ClassName option:
http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#classname

```
$.contextMenu({
  className: 'contextmenu-customwidth'
});
```

then use css:

```
.contextmenu-customwidth {
  width: 31px !important;
  min-width: 30px !important;
}
```

width only will not do the trick, you'll need min-width, too.

Comment: Voted up. But I had to combine yours and Aamirs answer (upvote, too), for sublevel-menus. According to your solution I first passed the custom class name to the contextmenu-constructor, then I created the css rule `.contextmenu-customwidth ul li { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: Thanks for upvote. The question didn't mention sublevels, so I didn't include them, but your solution obviously works

Answer (score 0):

Just open it's css file and customise accordingly if you have expertise in cascading style.

Comment: I dont have any css file with me for context menu except the jquery file that i am using ..

Comment: All the css that is being used can be seen in the post in the HTML